# Swift: Is it bad practice to access the AppDelegate window in order to get the superview of any view?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have class which is supposed to display a custom notification banner to let the user know if, for example, an API call succeeded or not. Currently, if you want to use this class, you have to pass in the `SuperView` in order for the banner to appear on the right view. I want to simplify it by creating a variable called `private let appWindow: UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!` in the notification banner class so that the dev does not have to worry about figuring what view is the super view. Then, in the notification banner class I set the constraints of the banner using `appWindow` as the `View`.

Basically, I want to always display the banner on top of every other `View` regardless if it's a tab bar controller, navigation controller, or any other type of `View` without knowing or passing in a view. The banner is a `UIView` itself.

Is it okay if I use the variable above? Is it good practice? Is there a better way to always get the top-most view or superview? If not, is there a better way to write the variable above?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is bad practice or not, as you can aways access that windows via `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath I think keyWindow is deprecated starting with iOS 13 so that wouldn't work without using an #available if statement.

Comment: @matt Ideally, that's what I would do but I don't want to limit the user's interaction with the current view controller. Plus they have to be able to dismiss the banner by swiping or the banner dismisses itself after 3 seconds.

Comment: You can certainly configure the dismiss with a presented view controller. The downside is that the user can’t interact with anything else, as you say.

Comment: How do you plan to unit test this? You *are* using tests, right? ()

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want your notification on top of ***EVERYTHING*** including things like alert views then adding to the existing window is not going to work; someone else can still add a view on top of you.  If you really want your view on top of everything use another window for your banner with `.greatestFiniteMagnitude` and then it will truly be on top of everything (unless someone else makes another window with level `.greatestFiniteMagnitude`; in that case whoever made the most recent window wins).

```
  private lazy var bannerWindow = {
    let bannerWindow = UIWindow()
    bannerWindow.backgroundColor = .clear
    bannerWindow.windowLevel = .init(.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    bannerWindow.isHidden = true
    return bannerWindow
  }
```

Comment: Someway somehow, I'm going to jam `.greatestInfiniteMagnitude` into a PR by the end of the week :)

Comment: Would this method allow the user to interact with the underlying view controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
private let appWindow: UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!
```

You cannot assume that the app delegate has a window property. If it doesn’t, you’ll just crash. Instead, ask the app itself about its windows.

Comment: I changed it to `guard let appWindow: UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window ?? UIWindow() else { return }` and then set the superview equal to appWindow `superview = appWindow`. But as long as the app is running, wouldn't there always be a window to refer to?

Comment: Yes but that is why I say ask the app. You know nothing about the user's app delegate. Try it yourself: In Xcode 11, make a new project and run your expression. Kaboom.